# Numpy fancy indexing suggestion needed

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

First of all, sorry for the less than perfectly descriptive title.

I have a (500, 500, 500) ndarray "A" of floats, and another (500, 500, 500) ndarray "Ind" of integers.

I want to form a third (500, 500, 500) ndarray "Anext", where the entry with index (x, y, z) in "Anext" is A[B[x, y, z], y, z].

I have looked into indexing, but I find it hard to come up with a useful solution. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `numpy.indices()` to create the index array of axis 1 and axis 2, here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(4, 4, 4)
ind = np.random.randint(0, 4, size=(4, 4, 4))

i0, i1, i2 = np.indices(a.shape)

b = a[ind, i1, i2]
```

to check the result:

```
for (i, j, k), v in np.ndenumerate(b):
    assert v == a[ind[i, j, k], j, k]
```

The shapes of `i0`, `i1`, `i2` are `(4, 4, 4)`, to save some memory, you can also use `numpy.ix_()`:

```
i0, i1, i2 = np.ix_(*[np.arange(d) for d in a.shape])
```

where `i1.shape`, `i2.shape` is `(1, 4, 1), (1, 1, 4)`